# Angular reactive forms cast the form.values to the model

Tags: angular, forms, reactive

I have a model represented by interface.

```
export interface MyModel {
  id: number;
  enabled: boolean;
  name: string;
  city: string;
  country: string;
}
```

When I am posting the reactive form all the values in `form.value` are string type. I tried to cast that by using `<MyModel>` syntax but didn't work.

```
submitForm(form: FormGroup, event: Event) {
   this.func(<MyModel>form.value);
}
```

Any ideas how woul you handle that?

I have my form setup like that:

```
setupForm() {
    this.userForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      id: [null, Validators.required],
      enabled: [null, Validators.required],
      name: [null, Validators.required],
      city: [null, Validators.required],
      country: [null, Validators.required]
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 7):

Something like this should work:

```
Object.assign(this.movie, this.editForm.value);
```

It will copy all of the matching properties from the edit form values into the original object.

Comment: how would you do same but without introducing a new `object(this.movie)`?

Comment: So you don't have any original data that you are using to populate the form?

Comment: the data coming from the form so there is no need to introduce a new variable to store the thing